Index Match Search Field with multiple rows in google sheets
I have a table of data where in column 1 I have connected rows 1-5 and in column 2 I have five different values belonging to the value in column 1.
Now I want to make a search function, where you can select the value from column 1 and it gives you all five rows of information belonging to that value.
Sample Sheet
However I only receive the first row of information. How am I able to get all five rows?
I am currently using the following function
=INDEX(B4:E400;MATCH(H20;B4:B400;0))

To easily take a copy of your sample data & test formulas (instead of winging it from screenshots), the recommended method is to create a markdown table. Use this tool to create the markdown_format & add it to your question. Additionally you can also share a sample sheet showcasing your input with realistic-demo data & expected output(manually entered). You may also use the anonymous blank sheet maker to ease the process of sharing


You may try:
=filter(B4:E,scan(,B4:B,lambda(a,c,if(c="",a,c)))=H3,byrow(C4:E,lambda(Σ,counta(Σ))))



Thank you, that actually works much better! However, there is still one issue coming up, when there are two values in column 3 that belong to one value in column 2, then again only the first row is shown instead of multiple. I added another screenshot to my initial post to showcase. Can this be fixed?

Did you go through the other comment about the recommended methods to share test data on stackoverflow?! Here's one example question you can maybe check out to get a clear picture on how to frame the question(with sample data)

Sorry, I didn't see. I added a sample sheet to my initial post. As you can see when selecting player 2 on the search function, there is one item missing. Could you help?

Updated the formula

Yes, that's perfect. Thanks alot!

@xnface A perfect answer probably deserves to be accepted. Why not read What does it mean when an answer is "accepted"?
